# What mechanisms made Stalinism triumphant in Russia?

Tags: soviet-union, political-history, stalin

What mechanisms would you guys think made Stalinism triumphant?

Firstly, what do you guys think, was Stalinism totalitarian? Was Stalin the absolute ruler over the totality of society and politics? Or perhaps a revised theory best suits the regime? Secondly, what would be your reason for Stalinism being successful? I'd say simply, because the Stalinist regime was never overthrown (coup nor revolution).

- **Coercion** must be discusses and the terror within and without the
  party. This is because it prevented social resistance and political opposition threatening the regime.
- **Ideology**? Do you guys believe that ideology legitimised the
  regime and its actions?
- Other forms of legitimation in the form of the **Cult of
  Personality** perhaps.
- Where there **political** factors which accounted for the triumph? What allowed Stalin to keep grip of power other than fear? Clientelism? The structure of the Stalinist Political system promoting centralised power?
- Soviet **Economics** should be discussed also. Yes it was triumphant but (and this may sound stupid) but why did the Stalinist regime want a prosperous economy? Was it to show the Capitalist states that Communism can advance and overtake them? Was it also to prepare for what Stalin foresaw as an inevitable war?
- Finally, probably the hardest to define is **'social'**. How did society make Stalinism triumphant? The totalitarian model would state that society's labour would be the reason for economic triumph, but would a revised theory perhaps discuss a soviet society which supported and maintained the regime in power? Where there classes which benefited from the terror for example? Did people prosper from Stalinist rule (oligarchs). I believe this to be the most interesting and hardest point of Stalinism. Your opinions on this will potentially re-define Stalinism from Totalitarian to something else.

Looking forward to hearing your views on this and others?

Comment: Wow, big question. You did a superb job of summarizing yourself the various aspects/theories so what can be added in answers is mostly references. But the house rules here forbid asking formreferencs so I am not sure you will get answers ;) Perhaps you might want to add some more specialized questions? P.S. Welcome and +1 of course!

Comment: A quibble: Soviet economy was not prosperous in the sense that people's quality of life was increasing. It was geared towards producing heavy machinery. So producing 50,000 tractors per year sounds great, but at the same time there was famine and rationing.

Comment: Yeah a big question indeed! Thank you for the welcome :). What do you mean by references? Yeah I'll definitely delve further with more specialised questions as I read on on the subject.

Comment: I would definitely agree that a command economy focusing on military, mineral extraction etc, would not really increase quality of life. But is the Stalinist regime won which triumphs or fails on the ethics of quality of life? I'd say labour efficiency would be important though. A malnourished society won't work amazingly well but a case study I have shows the power of communist ideology and how the workers believed in a better future

Comment: Read the help before posting.

Comment: Being legitimate and being in control for a long period without a coup is completely different question. You can be in control by simply executing all your potential enemies, but it doesn't make you legitimate.

Comment: @FelixGoldberg It is true that quality of life was low, however it wasn't high during the feudal/Tsar era neither. Small social improvements like free access to education/ social mobility can improve the observed quality of life  by the masses (same true for Hitler's Germany).

Comment: @Greg In regards to success, if being in control without a coup is great for Stalin (but isn't enough according to you for Stalinism to be triumphant), then how does legitimacy makes Stalinism triumphant?

Comment: @PG93 Sorry I don't understand your question, or what do you precisely mean by triumphant in a historical context, neither how your question is related to my comment.

Comment: @Greg "Being legitimate and being in control for a long period without a coup is completely different question." I have come to the conclusion that Stalinism was triumphant because there was no coup nor revolution and mechanisms which allowed him to remain in power were in turn successful. Yet you say that legitimacy is important also. I'm interested what you mean by this.

Comment: The answer to this question would depend on who you ask: A stalinist, a trotskyist or an anti-communist. Interestingly, stalinists and anti-communists would agree in that stalinism is the logical consequence of the october revolution.

Comment: Too many questions, needs to be split.

Comment: @PG93 No, i didn't say that.

Comment: PG93, you should also consider the cult of personality. That cult was made possible because movies and radio were completely new things in that day and age, and Stalin took advantage of it to make propaganda. Mao Zedong copied the cult of personality methods almost exactly and had basically the same rise to almost 100% absolute power, and I'm pretty sure movies and radio were still new to the Chinese during this period too.